# Display Table: titlekey not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag

I am working on a display table version 1.2 on Struts 2 application. I am having problem with fetching value for "titleKey" in my diplay table column.

`<display:column  titleKey="title.key"   >`

I am kinda sure that I do not have configuration problem. I tried fetching the same value outside the table as :

```
<s:text name="title.key"/>
```

I am successful in doing that.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any reason why DisplayTag would know about the S2 I18N mechanisms.

Either use DisplayTag's [I18N support](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/i18n.html) or by not using keys (e.g., the `"title"` attribute) and using values exposed by normal S2 mechanisms.

Comment: I do not have problem using "title" attribute, but I tried and failed; so I am looking for different alternatives. My whole purpose is to have column title as an image. I tried using <display:column  title="<img src=\"<%=request.getContextPath()%>/imageWeb/score_10.png\"/>" >. However, it didn't work.

Comment: I did solve this issue using "title" attribute without using request.getContextPath(). I am not sure why contextPath doesn't work in displayTag title.